# Evaluation of Information extraction a task

Tags: information-retrieval, evaluation-strategies

I have to evaluate my information extraction program. I have to evaluate it by the expectation-driven way.

I don't know what that means.

I would appreciate if you could help me.

Thx.

Comment: Can you give us more context?  Why do you think that you have to evaluate it "by the expectation-driven way"?  Where did you read that?  Who told you that?  If your course instructor told you that, you should them what they mean.  Overall, this sounds very broad.  What is the goal of your evaluation?  What questions do you want to be able to answer?  On what criteria do you want to evaluate it?  What reading (in the research literature) have you done about how others have evaluated their methods?  Can you edit the question to improve it?